# Button give $_GET extra parameter

Tags: php, html, button, get

I have two buttons in my form, one is for answer a question and the other is for copy the question.

```
<div id="question">
    <?php echo($question->content) ?>
</div>
<form action="script.php" method="GET" id="question">
    <input type="text" name="question">
    <button id="answer" onclick="document.getElementById('question').submit()">Answer the question</button>
    <button id="copy"   onclick="document.getElementById('question').submit()">Copy the question</button>
</form>
```

The URL of script.php look now like:
`script.php?question=sometext`

Now I want that when you click at the copy button the URL looks like this:
`script.php?question=sometext&copy`

And for the answer button:
`script.php?question=sometext&answer`

**EDIT:**

There are much answers where is said: "use `<input type>` instead of `<button>`"
The problem is that I can't use a input field as button because the button is outside my form. And I can't put it inside my form

Comment: why not using  `<input type="submit" name="copy" value="Copy..">` and `<input type="submit" name="answer" value="Answer...">`?

Comment: @AbcAeffchen, then you see nothing in the URL

Comment: just tested it and I get `script.php?question=sometext&answer=Answer+the+question`

Comment: You can use two `<input type='submit'>` with different name. It will solve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to use one hidden field and change it's name according to the pressed button. Something like the following:

```
<div id="question">
<?php echo($question->content) ?>
</div>
    <form action="script.php" method="GET" id="question">
        <input type="text" name="question">
        <input id="action" type="hidden" name="" value="">
        <button id="answer" onclick="document.getElementById('action').setAttribute('name','answer'); document.getElementById('question').submit()">Answer the question</button>
        <button id="copy"   onclick="document.getElementById('action').setAttribute('name','copy'); document.getElementById('question').submit()">Copy the question</button>
    </form>
```

Although this would give you the result you want at the url, it would be more appropriate to have as the hidden's field name the "action" and to change it's value to "copy" or "answer" through javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make two forms, with a hidden input field with the values. Then you get the extra parametrt in your url when submitting

Answer (score 0):

Change your form to the following

```
<form action="script.php" method="GET" id="question">
    <input id="question" type="text" name="question">
    <input id="answer" type="submit" name="answer" value="true">
    <input id="copy" type="submit" name="copy" value="true">  
</form>
```

url:

> ```
> script.php?question=hello&copy=true
> ```

Then you can check

```
if(isset($_GET['answer']) && $_GET['answer']=="true"){
//answer action
}

if(isset($_GET['copy']) && $_GET['copy']=="true"){
//copy action
}
```